# mongoose sub document array change value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I got a mongoose query where I want to change a comment. I receive the commentid from a react app. But it doesn't work, what could be the problem?

An example comment array follows

```
"comments": [       
    {
        "createdAt": "2018-11-22T08:28:36.881Z",            
        "_id": "5bf668b4001de72dc089c849",     // commentid       
        "comment": "111111111111",            
        "username": "kohahn21"        
    }, 
    ....
]
```

**What I have tried:**

```
edit = await Post.update(
    { 'comments._id' : commentid },
    { '$set' : { 'comments.$.comment' : comment  } }, 
    { new: true }
);

ctx.body = edit;
```

**`ctx.body`**

```
{
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "ok": 1
}
```

**Post Schema**

```
const Comment = new Schema({
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    username: String, 
    comment: String
});

const Post = new Schema({
    username: String,    
    comments: { 
        type: [Comment],
        default: []
    },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post',Post);
```

I would like to receive comments, which is a modified comment layout. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. But instead of 'items' it should be 'comments'.

Try `Post.update( { 'comments._id' : commentid }, {'$set' : { 'comments.$.comment' : comment } });`

btw the new flag is only available for find-and operators.

Comment: I would like to receive comments, which is a modified comment layout. What should I do?

Comment: [db.collection.findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)